# Получить Yandex xml в php

Tags: php, парсер, xml, яндекс-поиск

Есть запрос к яндексу
http://xmlsearch.yandex.ru/xmlsearch?user=МОЙ_НИК&key=КЛЮЧ&query=ЗАПРОС
Янд даже в случае ошибки возвращаеn xml
Пытаюсь его прочитать:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('СЮДА_ссылку');
print_r($xml);
```

с файлом test.xml у себя всё работает(
Почему не получить xls от яндекса?

Answer (score 1):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://адрессайта/xmlfile.php?en=12345');
echo $xml ->waybill["wbno"];
если не получится, то сделай var_dump($xml) и смотри, какие там где атрибуты
```

Comment: с моим файлом simplexml_load_file() работает, а от яндекса var_dump()=0